# Are ifModule mod_rewrite tags redundant in .htaccess mod_rewrite files

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Are the following opening/closing tags necessary for .htaccess mod_rewrite's? I've had .htaccess working without those, but just checking up on htaccess tutorials, many include this tag.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ... </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not necessary for mod_rewrite, as unknown directives are not interpreted, so it is more or less a style thing.

The tag can also used to perform test for not available modules with `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>`, so that you can use some other directives in that case.